# Why Does My JSoup getTitle() method return null and not the webpage title?

Tags: java, oop, jsoup

I'm pretty new to OOP and JSoup so I have no idea what is going wrong. I have a version of this code I made without using OOP that displays the title of the webpage correctly but my getTitle() method returns null in this code. I want it to return the name of the webpage. I used the debugger and saw that the document is connecting to the website.

```
package nld.dailyquotes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class DailyQuotes {

        private Document doc;
        private String title;


        public void setDocument(String url){

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .userAgent("Chrome")
                        .get();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public Document getDocument () {
            return doc;
        }

        public void setTitle(){
            title = doc.title();
        }

        public String getTitle(){
            return title;
        }

        public static void main (String[] args){
            DailyQuotes dq = new DailyQuotes();
            dq.setDocument("http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_inspirational.html");
            System.out.println(dq.getTitle());

}
```

Comment: You set the `doc` variable but never set anything to the `title` variable. At the point where you type `dq.getTitle()` you haven't set it to anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTitle` simply returns the value of the field `title`, which is by default `null`.  This is caused because you never call `setTitle`, which IMHO, is couterinterative.

That is, by convention, `setTitle` should apply a value, not retrieve one.  Instead, I would get rid of the `setTitle` method and simply use it's functionality in the `getTitle` method instead, for example...

```
    public String getTitle(){
        return doc == null ? null : doc.title();
    }
```

This also means you don't need the `title` field at all...

Comment: Thanks so much. I totally forgot about setTitle()...Yikes

Answer (score 0):

This code never calls `setTitle()`, so how exactly do you expect the title to be anything *other* than `null`?